# Assign random generated colors to values

Tags: c#, list, hyperlink, colors

I'm having problems joining 2 blocks of code.
I have this code to generate 4 random colors.

```
static Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Purple}; // Escolher as cores disponiveis
static Color GetRandomColor()
{
    var random = new Random();
    return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
}
```

I think the code is good but if it isn't please tell me.

I need to associate it to this code:

```
List<Utente> ListaUtente = new List<Utente>();
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Pedro", 555444333, "pedro@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Lucas", 555444333, "lucas91@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Rodrigo", 555444333, "rodrigo00@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Gaspar", 555444333, "gaspar@gmail.com"));
        ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Assis", 555444333, "assis@gmail.com"));
```

I need the program to output one of these random color (purple, red, yellow and green) and Write it on screen.

Something like:

```
Lucas - Green
Rodrigo - Red
```

How can I link these two blocks? I have full access to Lists and also the "Utente" Class attributes.

Comment: Can you put what you have already attempted?  Hard to know what you mean by "associate the blocks"

Comment: You should move the create of the instance of `Random` outside the `GetRandomColor` method.  If you call that method many times in quick succession (e. g. in a for loop) then you will likely get the same color returned multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  Can you just add a Color property to the Utente class and update the constructor so you can call this

```
ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(22, "Pedro", 555444333, "pedro@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
```

Then

```
foreach(Utente utente in ListaUtente)
{
    Console.WriteLine(utente.Name + " " + utente.Color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna try this solution and report in!

Comment: Im getting this error - Error 15 The name 'colors' does not exist in the current context. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Is all this in one class? I assumed this was homework or something so you were doing it all in Program.cs.  If you google that error you'll see it means that wherever you're declaring the color array is not the same scope as where you're using it.

Comment: Its the final project for an Hospital Managment System and Im having problems with this specific part. I have my main.cs file where I have this color generator code and a sepparte .cs file with utente class.

Comment: So where is colors at? Sounds like it's in your Program class (where the main function is).  Is that where you're building the ListaUtente?  Basically, it sounds like you need to set it up so that in main you instantiate the List<Utente> & iterate through it writing to the console. While the color generator stuff is in a static class you have access to from main and then the color & utente classes are defined in other files.  To keep things simple just stash all these classes in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?:

```
foreach(Utente utente in ListaUtente)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ GetRandomColor() } - { utente.Name }");
}
```

Also as Chris Dunaway points out, since you create a new instance of Random each time you call GetRandomColor() it will likely result in the same random number, since the default seed (system time) is the same (on faster machines) across all calls.

So a better way would be to extract the Random object out of then method.
Something like:

```
static Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Green,Color.Yellow,Color.Purple};
static Random random = new Random();
static Color GetRandomColor()
{
    return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
}
```

Comment: This will likely result in the same color for each instance since the instance of `Random` is being created inside the `GetRandomColor` method.  Not your fault, of course, but you might wish to point that out.